# Can't remove linux kernel module, yet also cannot install module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a simple scull module I have loaded with:

```
sudo insmod scull.ko
```

This worked fine, but I changed something in the src and recompiled, now I want to remove the old module and re-install it.

I've tried

```
sudo rmmod scull.ko
```

Which returns with `rmmod: ERROR: Module scull is not currently loaded`

Yet trying to re-install gives `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module scull.ko: File exists`

What the hell?

Comment: Try `rmmod scull`, not `rmmod scull.ko`, then `insmod scull.ko`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that as well and unfortunately it returns the same

Comment: What shows lsmod after you do insmod? I've seen similar thread here - on StackOverflow and it concerned Ubuntu and broken gcc as I remember.

Comment: Turns out this behavior occurred because of a prior kernel error that popped up in my kernel module init function, making the system behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

probably not relevant anymore, but it might be because (if you used sysfs) you didn't remove the sysfs class, and so it can't create the file.